# Selenium - set download directory in pytest.ini file

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I'm using py.test library. To set some default firefox preferences, I have pytest.ini file configured:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --driver=firefox --firefoxpref=plugin.state.java:2  --firefoxpref=offline-apps.quota.warn:5120000 --firefoxpref=pdfjs.disabled:true --firefoxpref=browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk:"text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/pdf" --firefoxpref=browser.download.panel.shown:false --firefoxpref=browser.download.folderList:2 --firefoxpref=browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting:false --firefoxpref=browser.download.dir:"C:\\firefox_downloads"
--firefoxpref=plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types:"application/pdf,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,application/vnd.fdf,application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml,application/pdf" --instafail --reruns=0
```

The problem is program does not catch directory, because it thinks : sign after C is between key and value and cannot assign it.
Any ideas how do fix this?

Comment: Escape it too?  `"C\:\\firefox_downloads"`

Comment: tried to, does not work